# How could I find the number of instances per fold, in my dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, histogram

I have been given an .npz file containing the data. I have explored the dataset, and noted that it has 5 datatypes:

```
cell_data = np.load("C:/Users/alexs/Documents/DataMining/cell-data.npz")
cell_data.files
```

Giving this at the output:

```
['images', 'counts', 'folds', 'compressed', 'allow_pickle']
```

As well as the image [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccpfy.png).

I am promised the dataset itself has 3 folds. The count is an Nx6 matrix with each row
corresponding to a single image patch and each column corresponding to the 6 cell types (called T1,T2, … , T6). The folds seems to be an 1xN matrix, however I am not sure, it consists of values ranging {0,2}.

How would I find out the number of instances per fold, and if this were possible, how would I find out the ranges of the folds, i.e. which instances belong to which folds (or group the instances into their own seperate array that respresents each fold like, fold1 = x, fold2 = x_2 etc.) to then plot a histogram for each fold, such that the counts of each cell type are plotted separately(6 plots in total)?

Comment: Please do not clutter your question with irrelevant stuff (intros, thanks, apologies etc - edited out).

Comment: I am guessing folds contains N entries which matches the number of images? Why not just map them together if this is the case?

Comment: @jhso Yeah, there are 2351 images, so its just a matter of how those images are divided into their 3 folds? Honestly im not sure how I would do that, im quite new to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since you are new to programming I will explain how indexing works (in numpy, which is an almost-universal mathametical library in python).

Say we have a variable `folds` which is defined as:

```
import numpy as np
folds = np.array([1,1,2,2,1,2,1,0,0,0,1,2,1,2,0,0,2,1])
```

We can easily count each fold occurrence by performing a list comprehension:

```
num_folds = 3
fold_counts = [np.sum(folds==I) for I in range(num_folds)]
#will return [5, 7, 6]
```

This will return the count as we are comparing each element in folds to the fold numbers 0, 1, and 2 (false if the element is not equal to I, true otherwise). We can sum boolean values (set them equal to 1) to get the total amount.

To answer your other question, we can use a similar bit of code to separate the images into their folds:

```
#assuming images are in a list:
image_folds = [[images[J] for J in np.where(folds==I)[0]] for I in range(num_folds)]

#assuming images are in an array of size [num_images, width, height, channels]
image_folds = [images[folds==I] for I in range(num_folds)]
```

Comment: So that will return the number of instances in all folds? If so, how do I modify it to return the number of instances in each fold, i.e. count number of 0's, 1's and 2's?

Comment: This will do that, edited to make it more clear

Comment: Oh! okay, I see exactly what you mean now, thank you. Do you know of a way I am able to group these fold instances together, in their own array? For example how I would group all the instances belonging to fold 1 together in their own seperate array? I would assume it would be something to do with the image array itself, and identifying which images corresponded to which element in the fold array?

Comment: In the last part of the code, you can just substitute a single index, ie. `image_fold_1 = images[folds==1]`, or run the code as is and call: `image_fold_1 = image_folds[1]`.

Comment: So if I have an array of counts, thats an 1x6 array for each of the images, where the 6 entries represent 6 different nuclei types, how would I for each fold, plot the histogram of counts of each cell type separately, and if thats possible how would I figure out how many images have counts within particular bins? Apologies in advance if I am pestering, its all a little confusing

Comment: Upon revision, could I find a folds corresponding average count for the first entries in the 1x6 nuclei array, put that into its own array, and then plot that array against the maximum value of the first entry of the 1x6 array?

Comment: Yes, particularly if you're dealing with numpy arrays this is all quite easy. Just get the `counts` matrix for each fold and use commands such as `np.histogram`, `np.mean`, and `np.sum`. I, and many others, use matplotlib.pyplot for plotting, too.

Comment: Hi Jhso, sorry to disturb you, im still struggling with this unforunately, do you think you'd be able to help me? I know its a simple problem but I still dont understand how I could do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230343/discussion-between-jhso-and-lambda).